Why is head method in pandas not showing the first few rows of a DataFrame?

I'm confused about the behavior of the .head() method in Pandas when applied to the DataFrame. Instead of showing the first 8 sequential rows, it displays rows with non-sequential indices, and only a few of the categories under the 'ocean_proximity' attribute are shown multiple times. There are 5 possible categories, but .head(8) shows just a random selection of 4 of them, with some categories appearing more than once. Could you explain why this happens?

If you have previously sorted housing then the index will be in a different order.  The first 8 rows of your dataframe will therefore not be 0-7 but the indices of the rows prior to sorting.  If you were to .reset_index() and then use .head(8) you would see the index as 0-7 and the same "ocean proximity" values.

DataFrame rows can be indexed by many types of hashable values. Pandas goes so far as to call it a "label" to constrast it with pure position based indexing. DataFrame.loc will lookup by label while DataFrame.iloc by index.
In your case, the index (or more appropriately, 'label') isn't just 0, 1, 2, etc.. This can be demonstrated with a simple test dataframe that we sort to scramble the original index.
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df=pd.DataFrame({"test":["one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six"]})
>>> df.head()
    test
0    one
1    two
2  three
3   four
4   five
>>> df2 = df.sort_values(by="test")
>>> df2.head()
    test
4   five
3   four
0    one
5    six
2  three

iloc will get rows by positional index
>>> df2.iloc[0]
test    five
Name: 4, dtype: object

while loc will get rows by label
>>> df2.loc[0]
test    one
Name: 0, dtype: object

Your dataframe has been transformed somehow, with those larger indexes ending up at the top. As for the categories, it's just luck which ones happen to be in the head.
